# Display integer value in minimum 2 digit before decimal in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to display int value in minimum 2 digit before decimal in sql server.
Is it possible than how pls rply?

Comment: It would be useful if you show an example - your description is somewhat confusing. You're formatting integer values, why would there be decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you really should be doing this formatting at the presentation layer, here is how to change `5` to `05`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), 5), 2);
```

In SQL Server 2012, you will be able to leverage the new [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function - much tidier and full .NET and culture support.